# Can I remove divs and change a style on content within an Iframe that is imported from another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I would like to use a form from another web-page (given the complex javascript on their end) but simply to remove certain divs (like when applying an addblock) and also, if possible, to alter the appearance.

Can I do that, and what would be the best and the easiest way to do it ?

Comment: If you can't control that other page, then no.

Comment: Not even with Javascript simply to block certain divs like you do with Ublock Origin ? Hmm...

Comment: No: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy An extension might do the trick.

Comment: And you can't rely a third-party page being available, they can add a "x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN" header at any time, then there will be only a warning page loaded into your iframe.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the potential problems, I need this as a temporary solution only while developing an independent one.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue. If iframe comes from different origin you won't be able to modify it due to [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

In other case [you can use contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

Also [this page may be useful](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication)